# .contains() method not working -- finding an int in array Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, contain

I have been looking for hours, all over the internet and SO, but cannot find anything that I understand! ( Very new at Java )

Upon compiling, it cannot find symbol of the contain method.
Here is the code:

```
public class LotteryTicket {
  private String nameOfBuyer;
  private int[] numberList;

  private boolean search(int val) {
    if (val >= 1 && val <= 50) {
      if (numberList.contains(val)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

I am very new at learning, and I do not know why this is happening.

Comment: What leads you to believe an array has a `contains` method? Did you perhaps mean to use a `List` instead?

Comment: `int[]` is a primitive array.  Array's don't have methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int[]` is a primitive array and does not have a method `.contains()`. If you used `List<Integer>` instead, that would give you a `.contains()` method to call.

Also, your search method must return a value even when `val < 1` or `val > 50`.

If you need `numberList` to be an `int[]`, you could try this:

```
private boolean search(int val) {
    if (numberList != null && val >= 1 && val <= 50) {
        for(int number : numberList) {
            if (number == val) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or, you could do this:

```
private boolean search(int val) {
    if (numberList != null && val >= 1 && val <= 50) {
        return Arrays.asList(numberList).contains(val);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `List` interface defines the method `contains`. Think of an interface as a contract that classes can "sign" (in Java this is done with the keyword `implements`) which says that the class must have certain things in its implementation. A very common implementation of the `List` interface is `ArrayList`, but Lists do not work very well with the primitive int type, so what you want to do is make an `ArrayList` of Integers.

The simplest way to make an ArrayList of Integers is to make an array of Integers first (I know, Java has a lot of weird steps required to get things working).

In addition, you want to make sure that boolean methods always return a boolean value or you will get a compiler error.

Here's a working example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LotteryTicket {
    private String nameOfBuyer;
    private List<Integer> numberList;

    private boolean search(int val) {
        return (val >= 1 && val <=50) && numberList.contains(val);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LotteryTicket lt = new LotteryTicket();
        Integer[] numberList = new Integer[] {2, 3, 4, 5, 42, 6};
        lt.numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(numberList));
        System.out.println(lt.search(42)); // prints "true\n"
        System.out.println(lt.search(25)); // prints "false\n"
    }
}
```